# How to fix Docker using the wrong Ruby path on Alpine

Tags: ruby, docker, sinatra, google-cloud-run

I have a very simple container running Sinatra in a Google Cloud Run. With no changes in the Dockerfile it recently stopped working.

When I try to run it I get the error:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- sinatra (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from main_wow.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:2.6.4-alpine3.9

ENV APP_HOME /WOW

WORKDIR $APP_HOME

ADD Gemfile* $APP_HOME/

RUN gem install bundler
RUN bundle install

ADD main_wow.rb $APP_HOME
ADD views/ $APP_HOME/views

# Start server
ENV PORT 3000
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["ruby", "main_wow.rb"]
```

Gemfile:

```
source "http://rubygems.org"

gem 'sinatra'
gem 'i18n'
```

First 10 lines of `main_wow.rb`:

```
require "sinatra"
require "net/http"
require "json"
require "i18n"
I18n.config.available_locales = :en

configure do
  set :public_folder, './views'
  set :bind, '0.0.0.0'
end
```

From what I could understand, it's trying to fetch the ruby gems from the major version 2.6.0, instead of 2.6.4.
I have already tried to create a link, to set ruby version on the Gemfile but none seems to work...

Comment: How are you running the image?  (What’s your `docker run` command or `docker-compose.yml` file?)

Comment: I'm running `docker build . -t naopira:latest` and then `docker run naopira` without a `docker-compose.yml`. Apparently it's not mandatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several guesses, I fixed it with `bundle exec` on the last line of the Dockerfile:

```
CMD ["bundle", "exec", "ruby", "main_wow.rb"]
```

Comment: Answering your own question is great as long as the question meets the guidelines. SO will give a timeout period, and when it expires you can select your own answer. Good job solving the problem!

Comment: Thanks for everything Tin! Your changes made everything much cleaner.

Comment: That's the point for being able to edit questions and answers once we get to a certain reputation. Stack Overflow is like a reference book, and grammar and readability are very important because we have people from around the world contributing. Sometimes I answer a question when I think the current answers don't address the issue correctly, and most of the time I now roam around cleaning and polishing. :-)